# Storing a c++ code on a real device

Tags: c++

Storing a c++ code on a real device
I wrote a c++ program for a lift and suppose I want to store it on a real lift. So that the lift will function according to my program. How do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go for some micro-controller like **Raspberry Pie** ([Link](http://www.raspberrypi.org/)) or some other ARM based micro-controller that can be programmed using C++. Just google for such micro-controllers and corresponding tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

By compiling for a x86 or x86_64, you're already storing your program on a "real device". What your probably asking is about compiling for an **embedded system**. For that, you can use a cross-compiler suitable to your platform. To actually **run** your program, you need to store it in the device's memory, the method by witch you do it is device-dependent.